# Something starts dhcclient for every interface on boot

Tags: boot, networking, dhcp

This is a cry for help. I have little hopes, but still...
As in Subj, after upgrade to 20 LTS my network is broken. Something starts dhclient for every network interface on boot, and I can't figure out who does it or how to disable it. Tried opening [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/isc-dhcp/+bug/1905472) but naturally no one cares

Same details here:

- Network is managed by ifupdown
- Netplan is not installed
- Network manger is disabled (masked)

Yet, at boot, SOMETHING starts dhclient for every network interface. This has disastrous results - dhcp request succeeds on physical interface that is a base for a vlan-based interface, causing real dhcp request on to fail on vlan interface.

Expected behavior - dhclient starts only for interfaces marked as dhcp in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Any advice is appreciated. I have no clue how to hunt down an entity that starts dhclient at boot. Logs show nothing. Please help.

Relevant portion of /etc/network/interfaces (the whole file has a single dhcp entry):

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto main0
iface main0 inet dhcp
    bridge-ports eno1
    mtu 1980

auto enp2s0f0
no-auto-down enp2s0f0
iface enp2s0f0 inet static
  address 192.168.251.33
  netmask 255.255.255.240
  mtu 9000

auto eno1
iface eno1 inet manual
  mtu 1980
```

edit2 - ip output

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1980 qdisc pfifo_fast master main0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether bc:ee:7b:dc:6d:25 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s25
3: enp2s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 68:05:ca:22:cb:e4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.251.33/28 brd 192.168.251.47 scope global enp2s0f0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::6a05:caff:fe22:cbe4/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: enp2s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 68:05:ca:22:cb:e5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.251.49/28 brd 192.168.251.63 scope global enp2s0f1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::6a05:caff:fe22:cbe5/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: main0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1980 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether bc:ee:7b:dc:6d:25 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.230/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global dynamic main0
       valid_lft 28437sec preferred_lft 28437sec
    inet6 fe80::beee:7bff:fedc:6d25/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


  accounts-daemon.service      loaded active running Accounts Service                                                
  acpid.service                loaded active running ACPI event daemon                                               
  apache2.service              loaded active running The Apache HTTP Server                                          
  atd.service                  loaded active running Deferred execution scheduler                                    
  avahi-daemon.service         loaded active running Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack                                         
  bluetooth.service            loaded active running Bluetooth service                                               
  colord.service               loaded active running Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles                     
  cron.service                 loaded active running Regular background program processing daemon                    
  cups-browsed.service         loaded active running Make remote CUPS printers available locally                     
  cups.service                 loaded active running CUPS Scheduler                                                  
  dbus.service                 loaded active running D-Bus System Message Bus                                        
  gdm.service                  loaded active running GNOME Display Manager                                           
  irqbalance.service           loaded active running irqbalance daemon                                               
  kerneloops.service           loaded active running Tool to automatically collect and submit kernel crash signatures
  libvirtd.service             loaded active running Virtualization daemon                                           
  lxcfs.service                loaded active running FUSE filesystem for LXC                                         
  mdmonitor.service            loaded active running MD array monitor                                                
  ModemManager.service         loaded active running Modem Manager                                                   
  networkd-dispatcher.service  loaded active running Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd                          
  nmbd.service                 loaded active running Samba NMB Daemon                                                
  nvidia-persistenced.service  loaded active running NVIDIA Persistence Daemon                                       
  polkit.service               loaded active running Authorization Manager                                           
  rinetd.service               loaded active running rinetd.service                                                  
  rsyslog.service              loaded active running System Logging Service                                          
  rtkit-daemon.service         loaded active running RealtimeKit Scheduling Policy Service                           
  smbd.service                 loaded active running Samba SMB Daemon                                                
  ssh.service                  loaded active running OpenBSD Secure Shell server                                     
  switcheroo-control.service   loaded active running Switcheroo Control Proxy service                                
  systemd-journald.service     loaded active running Journal Service                                                 
  systemd-logind.service       loaded active running Login Service                                                   
  systemd-machined.service     loaded active running Virtual Machine and Container Registration Service              
  systemd-timesyncd.service    loaded active running Network Time Synchronization                                    
  systemd-udevd.service        loaded active running udev Kernel Device Manager                                      
  udisks2.service              loaded active running Disk Manager                                                    
  uml-utilities.service        loaded active running LSB: start and stop UML networking services                     
  unattended-upgrades.service  loaded active running Unattended Upgrades Shutdown                                    
  upower.service               loaded active running Daemon for power management                                     
  user@1000.service            loaded active running User Manager for UID 1000                                       
  user@121.service             loaded active running User Manager for UID 121                                        
  vmware-USBArbitrator.service loaded active running LSB: This services starts and stops the USB Arbitrator.         
  vmware.service               loaded active running LSB: This service starts and stops VMware services              
  whoopsie.service             loaded active running crash report submission daemon                                  
  wpa_supplicant.service       loaded active running WPA supplicant
```

Comment: Please post your /etc/network/interfaces and let us know what network interfaces you have on your computer.

Comment: Added to the post, Thanks! The issue is with dhclient running on eno1 early at boot. The current workaround - "ifdown eno1; ifup eno1; ifup main0" after boot

Comment: That is my very first question on askubuntu. It is already downvoted, with "this question does not show any research effort and is unclear/unuseful". way to go, way to go...

Comment: OK, I have some more questions. What interfaces you have? Post output of 'ip a' and what services are running? Output of 'systemctl list-units --type=service --state=running' Why are you using a iface main0 and not eno1 for dhcp?

Comment: The main0 has to be a bridge for a number of reasons (VM attach, net config change on FTTP outage, etc).  I fail to see where it is going... :(  There is nothing in my config that is supposed to start dhcpc for eno1.  I wonder if there is some kind of kernel audit settings, to spew all launched processes to klog...

Comment: Just to make sure I understand right. DHCP is always supposed to get an IP on boot. If you don't want to get an IP on boot you can remove dhcp in 'iface main0 inet dhcp' and set your IP manually.

Comment: Wow, just wow... You really trying to answer the question you did not understand in a first place...

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be intitramfs bug (the referenced bug updated). In Focal they changed the AOE script to call configure_networking in functions.sh . This is a mega-function that is triggered by netboot or net root (nfs,iscsi and now aoe). Unfortunately configure_networking always tries to bring a net interface to get an ip (which is not required for aoe) and in absence of ip=/device= command line args, the default is to try every protocol (bootp,dhcp) on every interface. Ouch.

The workaround is to add ip=none to kernel line, or comment out configure_networking from local_top/aoe .

p.s. My first question here. I've got two absolutely un-relevant answers and a down-vote. Very cool, thanks.